# Elasticsearch: has_child query with children aggregation - bucket counts are wrong

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm attempting to find parents based on matches in their children and retrieve children term aggregations for the matches.  For some reason, the bucket count for the children aggregation is showing a higher count than actual results (I would be happy if it showed the count of the parents - or the children - in the particular children bucket).

The query is similar to the following (NOTE: I use the filtered query as I will later add a filter in addition to the query):

```
{
"query" : {
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "has_child" : {
            "type" : "blog_tag",
            "query" : {
                "filtered" : {
                    "query" : {
                        "term" : {
                            "tag" : "something"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"aggs" : {
    "my_children" : {
        "children" : {
            "type" : "my_child_type"
        },
        "aggs" : {
            "field_name" : {
                "terms" : {
                    "field" : { "blog.blog_tag.field_name" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide the result of that query and show why it is wrong?

Comment: @AndreiStefan I think the problem is that I want the scope of the children aggregation (on 'blog_tag') to be confined to only those children that match the query (the inner hits). In other words, referring to the example, I want the buckets for the 'field_name' of the 'blog.blog_tag' which has the 'tag' matching the query ('something'). As it stands now, the scope includes any 'blog' with any 'blog_tag' that has a 'tag' (has_child query term) - not just the 'blog_tag' that matched the query.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I see there is an aggregation filter which could be used if my query was instead a filter - but don't see anything for narrowing the aggregation scope by query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was as noted in the comments.  The solution was to filter the aggregation with the query,

```
"query" : {
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "has_child" : {
            "type" : "blog_tag",
            "query" : {
                "filtered" : {
                    "query" : {
                        "term" : {
                            "tag" : "something"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"aggs" : {
    "my_children" : {
        "children" : {
            "type" : "my_child_type"
        },
        "aggs" : {
            "results" : {
                "filter" : {
                    "query" : {
                        "filtered" : {
                            "query" : {
                                "term" : {
                                    "tag" : "something"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "aggs" : {
                    "field_name" : {
                        "terms" : {
                            "field" : { "blog.blog_tag.field_name" }
                       }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution. Note that the results aggregation does not have has_child, Also if you have filters on the parent document, you can just only have them in the query and not in the results aggregation.